# NameError for ActionMailer within ActionController

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, actionmailer, actioncontroller

I'm on Rails 3.0, and I pretty much followed the steps on the [API](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionMailer/Base.html) to define a mailer by doing

```
rails generate mailer Notifier
```

Within my controller, I call `Notifier.mytemplate(...)`

When I go to the page, I see an error:

```
uninitialized constant MyController::Notifier
```

Seems like something is not getting initialized correctly, and it's not realizing that Notifier is already defined in `app/mailers/notifier.rb`

Comment: Okay... my friend told me to try `rails c` and I get an error saying that I'm missing readline. Looks like my Ruby environment might be messed up, reinstalling. Why does my RVM install command look like `rvmsudo rvm install 1.9.2 --with-zlib-dir=$rvm_path/usr --with-openssl-dir=$rvm_path/usr --with-readline-dir=$rvm_path/usr`